# Is there any way to manually produce an answer in a browser using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, browser-console

So I'm not 100% if the thing I'm asking for is called `answer`. If you open your browser's console, in any chromium-based browser it should look something like this: [image]

And in Firefox it looks something like this: [image]

It's the thing that the console writes to if you use something like `document.getElementById`.

Is there any way to write to said result/answer?

Comment: There have now been 2 close requests stating that I should provide more details and clarity. However, I don't know what details are needed so please write a comment instead of flagging it.

Comment: Are you asking how to write to the browser console?  Have you tried `console.log('some value')`?

Comment: @AlexanderNied if you do that the value next to the arrow says `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The arrow to the left is the console telling you that some function returned some value.

If you paste this code to the console, and then run it by typing `foo()` and pressing enter:

```
function foo() {
   return "bar"
}
```

It will return the string "Bar", and the icon you mentioned will appear, indicating that some function simply returned a value and did nothing with it.

Edit: As others mentioned, if you use it with `console.log("foo")`, the arrow will appear with `undefined` because the function `console.log()` doesnt return anything, it explicity prints on the browser's console, but doesn't return any value. Any function that doesn't return a value, the console will return back that arrow with `undefined`.

Edit2: A full reference of what you can do with console is here: [W3Schools Console Object](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_console.asp)